# Clean and clever proofs to show an automorphism which sends elements of a group to their squares is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I am still practicing for a qual exam in algebra (freebie qual I can take the week before grad school starts). I have learned a lot about good proof writing just from the previous two post but I'm sure there will always be helpful feedback I can receive. I'm especially interested in learning to write cleaner and more clever proofs. I checked the qual prep page for my university and they actually give points for more interesting ways of proving a statement so I am also interested in methods which are a little beyond the level of math in the question. Here's my attempt at the proof...

> $\bf{Theorem}$: If $\phi : G \rightarrow G$ given by $\phi(g) = g^2$
>   is an automorphism of a group $G$, then $G$ must be abelian
>
> $\mathbf{Proof}$:
>
> Note that $\phi(fg) = \phi(f)\phi(g) = f^2g^2$ and $\phi(fg) = fgfg$
>
> Applying the proper group operations on $fgfg = f^2g^2$ we get $gf =
>  fg$
>
> Since $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary in $G$ we have that $G$ is abelian and
>   we are done.

My immediate self-critique is that if we are trying to prove that $G$ has a property the proof should start with elements of $G$ and not a map on elements of $G$ for the sake of clarity. But I may be overthinking or seeing it from my perspective and the perspective of a professor grading my qual.

Comment: I don't agree with the self-critic. The Theorem starts with $\phi$, so why not the proof, too.

Comment: The statement of the theorem is too restrictive. It's abelian if $\phi$ is a homomorphism. There are groups where it is a homomorphism but not an automorphism and it still implies that they are abelian. Notice the proof doesn't use injectivity or surjectivity in any way.

Comment: @MattSamuel is it possible that on a qual this sort of question might be intended to see which students will identify that the statement could have been more general?

Comment: Beats me. My written qualifying exam was nothing like that, it was just tricky problems involving first year material, but they were problems with some known themes that were provided by the department that we were told to study in order to pass, like Jordan canonical form. Your qualifying exam need not be at all similar, it's entirely dependent on the program.

Comment: @MattSamuel I think the homomorphism would have to be surjective at least otherwise we couldn't guarantee $fg = \cdots = gf$ for ever $f, g \in G$ just for the elements that are in the pre-image of $\phi$. I'm not sure if there's any reason it has to be injective though I suspect there might be. Did I get something wrong there? Oh wait if it's only surjective and $g, g'$ both map to $g^2$ we can't show that $g'$ commutes with $g$. Is that about right?

Comment: It works even if injectivity and surjectivity utterly fail, with $\phi(g) $ being equal to the identity for all $g$. Try it. All you need is that $ffgg=fgfg$, it doesn't matter what those values actually are, just that they're equal.

Comment: @MattSamuel, if $\phi$ sends everything to the identiy how would we even have $\phi(g) = g^2$ on any $G$ but the trivial group?

Comment: I'm saying that if $g^2$ is the identity for all $g$, then the same proof shows that the group is abelian. This happens when the group is the direct product of some number of copies of the cyclic group of order $2$, which you usually are not aware of when you do this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is basically correct, but lacks an introduction and some details, in my opinion. Here is how I would do it:

Consider any  $g,g'\in G$ and transform $gg'$ by $\phi$, which is an automorphism by hypothesis – which means that
$$\phi(gg')=(gg')^2= gg'\,gg'=\phi(g)\phi(g')=gg\,g'g'.$$
By the  (left and right) cancellation rule in a group, we instantly deduce that for any $g, g'\in G$,
$$g'g=gg' .$$